# String back from NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding

Tags: objective-c, emoji, decoding

I encoded the string incase there is emoji in the text to send it to server and  to save it in backend database

```
NSRange range = [qrnamestr rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString *str = [qrnamestr substringWithRange:range];
NSData *codePointData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
u_int32_t codePoint = *((u_int32_t *)(codePointData.bytes));
NSString *escapedEmoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&#%d", codePoint];
```

It is working fine on the web end. But how to decode it back to normal string to display it on device. I tried with number of solutions provided on stack, but no one works.

Comment: is `escapedEmoji` the string that you want to decode back to an emoji?

Comment: Finally, I displayed the NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoded content to UITextView, as textview shows compatibility with NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoded string. Thanks to all for looking into my query.